# Creating generic Expression

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression

I have a problem regarding generic expressions.

I have an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and I want to convert the `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<Y, bool>>`. The object of class `T` has the same properties as the class Y.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Your two basic approaches are to either walk the tree of the expression and recreate a similar one but to which all uses of `T` are replaces with `Y`, or you could accept an `Expression<Func<Y, T>>` and invoke that, along with another expression, and use that composition to create the final expression.

Comment: If they have the same properties, why not use inheritance? That should solve the problem right away.

Comment: Better yet, an Interface.

Comment: @meilke OP may not be able to modify T, Y or both.

Answer (score 1):

The "preferred" way to do this is use a Interface that contains the property you care about.

```
interface IMyProp
{
    string SomeProp {get;}
}

class T : IMyProp
{
    public string SomeProp 
    {
        get
        {
            //Some complicated logic
        }
    }
}

class Y : IMyProp
{
    public string SomeProp {get; set;}
}
```

The just code your expression to `Expression<Func<IMyProp, bool>>`

However it is understandable that you can not always do this, for situations like this you can use a library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

```
class T
{
    public string SomeProp 
    {
        get
        {
            //Some complicated logic
        }
    }
}

class Y
{
    public string SomeProp {get; set;}
}


//Some initiation code somewhere else in your project
public static void InitializeMappings()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<T, Y>();
}

public static IQueryable<Y> FilterOnTAndMapToY(IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T,bool>> filter)
{
      return source.Where(filter).Project().To<Y>();
}
```

Now this does not exactly turn your `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` in to a to `Expression<Func<Y, bool>>` but it does let you use your `T` expression and use it to get a `Y` result after the filtering has been applied.

The way AutoMapper's [Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) work is the querys and casts to go from `T` to `Y` happen all server side when you are doing LinqToEntities. So you could even do

```
public static IQueryable<Y> MultiFilterCast(IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T,bool>> tTypeFilter, Expression<Func<Y,bool>> yTypeFilter)
{
      var filteredStage1 = source.Where(tTypeFilter);
      var castToY = filteredStage1.Project().To<Y>();
      var filteredStage2 = castToY.Where(yTypeFilter);
      return filteredStage2;
}
```

both `tTypeFilter` and `yTypeFilter` will be applied server side before you get the result set.

Comment: If you can change T and Y, some variation of this is probably ideal, but the one instance where I needed a similar thing to this, I could not modify T, only Y.

Comment: @lukegravitt AutoMapper works great when you can not change T and Y. If you are not a 1 to 1 mapping like in the OP's case then you use the [ForMember](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation) function when you call `CreateMap<T,Y>()` and do any of the non matching mapping by hand.

Comment: That'll teach me not to read the entire answer carefully! AutoMapper looks like it may have solved my issue actually.

Comment: That would work if I want to filter by T. The problem is that the source I want to filter is of type Y. And the service that is calling the filter method doesn't know the type (Y) I want to filter by.